# Antiderivative of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$, and computing the derivative of $x^2\cos(x^{-1})$ at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am trying to understand Daniel Fischer's answer to this question [Antiderivative of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150453/antiderivative-of-sin-frac1x)

I understand the ideas and every step except for the part where he said

> The first part $x^2\cos(x^{−1})$ is easily seen to be differentiable at $0$ with derivative $0$ there

But isn't $x^2\cos(x^{−1})$ not defined at $x=0$? So how can we talk about its derivative there? I can see that the *limit* at $0$ exists, but it's still not defined there. Is he using some properties of $F'$ that I am not seeing? Or do we actually have somehow have this point defined to be zero at zero? Since by [Show that the function $g(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x}) ,(g(0) = 0)$ is everywhere differentiable and that $g′(0) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232672/show-that-the-function-gx-x2-sin-frac1x-g0-0-is-everywhere) we know that the derivative is zero if we define $x^2\cos(x^{−1})$ to take the value zero at zero, so do we have this? Is there something about how we define $F$ and/or $F'$ that forces this to be true?

I can't really be sure of this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd say with about a 99.9% chance of probability that yes, they are are talking about the function with the "hole" removed, i.e. by defining the function at 0 to be its limit.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 cos(1/x)$ is actually defined at $x=0$. It can be seen by applying squeeze theorem.
As $-1\leq cos(1/x) \leq 1$ for all $x$ hence
$-x^2\leq x^2 cos(1/x)\leq x^2$.
The limits $-x^2$ and $x^2$ as $x$ approaches $0$ are $0$.
Thus at $x=0$, $x^2 cos(1/x)$ is squeezed between $0$'s and hence itself $0$.

Comment: Technically, $x^2cos(1/x)$ **isn

Comment: No,  the limit is defined at 0.  The function itself isn't unless we manually add the point.

Comment: @Alan So we have got a removable singularity at $x=0$?

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT Correct, and once it is removed it is differentiable there as well (Though not twice-differentiable)